# What is this tree from the NW?

Tags: identification, trees

Found in Portland Oregon. It came from a tree about 10-12 ft tall. It smells very sweet, almost like Jasmine.

Does anyone know what it is?

[image: unknown tree]

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a tree - if it was in a tree, it's because it climbed up into it, as it often does if it can. It's a climbing plant called Clematis vitalba, common name Traveller's Joy. Many other forms of clematis are incorrectly called Traveller's Joy, so best to stick to the botanical/Latin name of C. vitalba if you need to tell anyone precisely what it is. Grows wild in the UK and Europe, often found in hedgerows; I'm not sure whether it grows wild in parts of America too, or whether this one has been deliberately planted. Flowers July through to September and is, indeed, fragrant.

http://www.wildflowersofireland.net/plant_detail.php?id_flower=290&wildflower=Traveller%27s%20Joy

Comment: I believe Prairie Travelers Joy is a cultivar of C. vitalba. I have a similar clematis also developed, like Prairie Traveler's Joy, by Frank Skinner.  This plant is extremely vigorous and easily grows 10 feet (3 M) tall in  a season.  The fragrance is pleasant and not overwhelming.

Comment: @kevinsky - Prairie TJ is a hybrid with clematis ligusticifolia - its flowers are whiter than C.vitalba, which  is probably in the mix with it somewhere.Even so, C vitalba is the original, naturally occurring plant  called traveller's joy... now annoyingly applied to many hybrid forms.  Well, I find it annoying, but then  I find common names annoying generally;-)

Comment: @Bamboo , I am not entirely convinced that it is Travellers Joy. It produces a smell that is very sweet and subtle, which reminds me of my grandmothers garden. It assuredly came from a tree without any vines/climbers. The next time I am in the area, I will take another picture.

Comment: I'll be interested to see it, but check for something growing next to, or some feet away, or nearby  ending up in the tree when you do take pics...